# Enlarge the arrows on the edges

Tags: tikz-pgf

I have written the following code for a directed graph, but the size of arrow is too small.
My question is how can I enlarge the size of the arrows

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    [x=1.3cm, y=1cm,
        every edge/.style={
            draw,
            postaction={decorate,
                        decoration={markings,mark=at position 0.5 with {{\arrow{>}}}}
                       }
            }
    ]

    \draw (0,1) node [circle,fill, inner sep=2pt] {};
    \draw (2,1) node [circle,fill, inner sep=2pt] {};
    \draw (0,0) node [circle,fill, inner sep=2pt] {};
    \draw (2,0) node [circle,fill, inner sep=2pt] {};
    \draw (0,-1) node [circle,fill, inner sep=2pt] {};
    \draw (2,-1) node [circle,fill, inner sep=2pt] {};
    \path

        (0,1)edge(2,1)
        (2,0)  edge (0,0) 
        (0,-1) edge (2,-1) 

        ;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Answer (score 2):

You can add options to `\arrow{>}`. For example `\arrow[scale=2]{>}` will double the size (and line width) of the arrow. If you want a different line width you can also add `line width` option.

For example:

[image: Result]

Comment: It does not change!!!

Comment: @Jivid Well, it changes in my MWE. Perhaps other style definitions in yours are interfering. The MWE you posted was not compilable and I was fixing it. If you try to change `\arrow{>}` by `\arrow[scale=2]{>}` in this MWE you should see a change.